# javascript best practice define variable (namespace) check is not already defined

Tags: javascript

Wanted to get opinions from the experts, I am declaring a variable that will act as the namespace for my application javascript code, but i want to check it is not already defined.

this code is terse and 'seems' to work - any reason I should avoid this and use typeof 'undef' checking instead?

```
var MY_NAMESPACE = MY_NAMESPACE || {};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the standard way of doing it. See [Matt Snider's analysis](http://mattsnider.com/javascript/namespace-function/) of the YUI [`YAHOO.namespace` function](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yahoo/#namespace) which uses this same check (Also for a look at how to make it easy to create namespaces).

Matt's code, which he adapted from YUI to namespace off the `window` object instead of the `YAHOO` object:

```
window.object_mes_namespace = function() {   
    var a = arguments,    
        o = window,   
        i = 0,   
        j = 0,   
        tok = null,   
        name = null;   

    // iterate on the arguments   
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i = i + 1) {   
        tok = a[i].split(".");   

        // iterate on the object tokens   
        for (j = 0; j < tok.length; j = j + 1) {   
            name = tok[j];             
            o[name] = o[name] || {};   
            o = o[name];   
        }   
    }   

    return o;   
}
```

Note the `o[name] = o[name] || {};` line, which parallels your example.

Answer (score 2):

Although what you posted is seen commonly, I personally don't think it's the best way to do it.

1. `MY_NAMESPACE` could evaluate to false for several reasons other than `undefined` -- the variable could really be defined but be `0` or `false` or an empty string, and you might end up replacing this value.
2. `MY_NAMESPACE` could evaluate to true for several reasons other than already being an object -- it could be a non-zero number or `true` or a string, and this will cause your script to silently fail, because adding properties to a primitive will fail without an error.

Really, the best way depends on what your goal is. If you don't want to pollute an existing variable/namespace, you should do a `typeof` check and stop if the variable is already defined but not an object:

```
if (typeof MY_NAMESPACE == 'undefined') {
  // create a new namespace
  MY_NAMESPACE = {};
}

if (typeof MY_NAMESPACE == 'object') {
  // go ahead
} else {
  // MY_NAMESPACE was already defined, but it is not an object
  // your script will fail if you continue, so do what you must and stop
}
```

If your script *must* work, just blindly create the namespace without any checks (of course, I'm not recommending that you do this).

---

**Edit:** (in response to @jball's comment, thought I'd just add it here)

- If this namespace is part of a library that you're developing, then it is imperative that you name your namespace carefully to avoid collision. If you do encounter a collision, it's better to just stop loading your library than mix your library with another and get unexpected results.
- If this namespace is just for your own application, it should be fairly simple to pick a name that isn't used by any libraries that you're using.

Comment: If you've picked a namespace that collides with some other variable or namespace, how do you handle all your namespace dependent code? Just don't run it? Hopefully all your other JS is namespaced as well, and uniquely. If not, come up with a better nomenclature?

Comment: Also, blindly creating without any checks means that you can define part of your namespace, and then overwrite it when you are defining/extending it later... the point of the namespace check is to ensure that your namespace is only created if it doesn't exist, so that you can ensure all your js functionality written in any number of files is all contained in the namespace.

Comment: @jball: I specifically mentioned that I'm not suggesting the blind approach. As for defining parts of the namespace, there are better ways to do that than `namespace || {}`.

Comment: The other point I was making is that namespaces are designed to be declared in each module that uses them, and the declaration in module `foo` needs to respect the fact that I may very well write other modules in that same namespace and use them before or after I use `foo`. Namespacing *needs* to be a "check if exists or create" operation in order to have modularity.

Comment: @jball: I believe you missed the second part of my previous comment -- nevertheless, I've updated my answer to clarify that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your `if object .. else` section is not correct. Your current check will fail if `MY_NAMESPACE` is a function as well as if it is a primitive. A check for whether `MY_NAMESPACE` is mutable may very well be called for though.

Comment: @jball: Indeed it will fail if it is a function, that can be fixed if necessary. And of course it is *meant* to fail if it is a primitive, because continuing in that case makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is already the preferred way.

But your statement does nothing, unless you leak `MY_NAMESPACE` into another scope, because `MY_NAMESPACE` is `MY_NAMESPACE`.

Comment: Example of "leaking into another scope" - `window.MY_NAMESPACE = window.MY_NAMESPACE || {};`

Answer (score 1):

I like the [YUI example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/2/) and use it for all my Apps.  In yours, you're re-assigning MY_NAMESPACE no matter what, which isn't a huge deal, but I prefer to avoid that assignment if it's not necessary.

```
if (typeof myNamespace == "undefined" || !myNamespace) {
    var myNamespace = {};
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, your check is different than the YUI code's check. The OP's code is much closer to the YUI style of namespace creation.

Comment: From YUI2
if (typeof YAHOO == "undefined" || !YAHOO) {
  var YAHOO = {};
}

Comment: true for the `YAHOO` variable, but not for how it creates namespaces below it. Code dump: `YAHOO.namespace = function() { var a=arguments, o=null, i, j, d; for (i=0; i<a.length; i=i+1) { d=(""+a[i]).split("."); o=YAHOO; /* YAHOO is implied, so it is ignored if it is included */ for (j=(d[0] == "YAHOO") ? 1 : 0; j<d.length; j=j+1) { o[d[j]]=o[d[j]] || {}; o=o[d[j]]; } } return o; };` - Note in particular the `o[d[j]]=o[d[j]] || {};` statement.

Comment: true but i think his question is about defining a simple namespace, not writing a method to create namespaces as you've posted.